# Insert a KML File in a Google Map Website Script

Tags: javascript, google-maps, joomla

I have a javascript File where i want to insert kml Map Overlay. I think it´s not the problem about knowing which code to add, but more where it has to be add exactly.

This is the Javascript File of a Template:

```js
// Google maps function
var gkMapInitialize = function() {
  var maps = jQuery('.gk-map');
  var mapCenters = [];
  var mapAreas = [];
  
  maps.each(function(i, map) {
   map = jQuery(map);
 mapCenters[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(0.0, 0.0);
   
   
 if(map.data('latitude') !== undefined && map.data('longitude') !== undefined) {
  mapCenters[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(
       parseFloat(map.data('latitude')), 
       parseFloat(map.data('longitude'))
      );
 }
   
   
   var mapOptions = {
     zoom: parseInt(map.data('zoom'), 10) || 12,
     center: mapCenters[i],
     panControl: map.data('ui') === 'yes' ? true : false,
     zoomControl: map.data('ui') === 'yes' ? true : false,
     scaleControl: map.data('ui') === 'yes' ? true : false,
     disableDefaultUI: map.data('ui') === 'yes' ? false : true,
     mapTypeControl: map.data('ui') === 'yes' ? true : false,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER
        }
   };
 
   mapAreas[i] = new google.maps.Map(map.get(0), mapOptions);

  

   var link = jQuery('<a>', { class: 'gk-map-close'});
   link.insertAfter(map);
   // custom events for the full-screen display
   var marker = null;


   map.on('displaybigmap', function() {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: mapCenters[i],
       map: mapAreas[i],
       animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });
    
   

    setTimeout(function() {
     google.maps.event.trigger(mapAreas[i], 'resize');
    }, 300);
    
    mapAreas[i].setCenter(mapCenters[i]);

    if(map.data('line') !== undefined) {
     var points = map.data('line').split(';');
     var polyline = [];
     
     points = points.filter(function(x) { 
      return x != '';
     });
     
     jQuery.each(points, function(i, item) {
      var coords = item.split(',');
      polyline.push(new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(coords[0]), parseFloat(coords[1])));
     });
     
     if(points.length) {
      var path = new google.maps.Polyline({
       path: polyline,
       geodesic: true,
       strokeColor: '#ff0000',
       strokeOpacity: 1.0,
       strokeWeight: 2
      });
      
      path.setMap(mapAreas[i]);
     }
    }
   });
   
   if(maps[i].hasClass('static')) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: mapCenters[i],
       map: mapAreas[i],
       animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });
   }
   
   map.on('hidebigmap', function() {
    if(marker) {
     marker.setMap(null);
    }
   });
  });
  
  jQuery(window).resize(function() {
   mapAreas.each(function(map, i) {
    map.setCenter(mapCenters[i]);
   });
  });
};
```

I tried with snippets i found in the web like:

```
var geoXml = new GGeoXml("http://www.mawosoft.de/datei.kml");
  map.addOverlay(geoXml);
```

or

```
var layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('<url of your KML file>');
```

layer.setMap(map);

on different positions in the file above, but it doesn´t show the kml overlay in the map.

Is there anyone could help me?

thanks a lot and Regards,

Elisa

Comment: Do you have a valid kml file? You might want to try the kml file url from this [demo](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml).

Comment: Hello ztan, thank you for your answer! Yes i tried also the demo kml files but it doesn´t work. I put in the code:   var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ggeoxml/cta.kml'
  });
  ctaLayer.setMap(map); at severall positions, but i don´t know where exaktly...